# Sentry send successful events to perfomance monitoring but not to issues

Tags: yii2, sentry

We implemented sentry monitoring in Yii2 app with [this package](https://github.com/notamedia/yii2-sentry) for basic logging. And for perfomance monitoring we basically start transaction in `beforeAction` and stop transaction in `afterAction`

Config:

```
$config = [
    'bootstrap' => [
        'sentry' => 'sentry',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => SentryTarget::class,
                    'dsn' => (string)getenv('SENTRY_DSN'),
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                    'context' => true
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'sentry' => [
            'class' => Sentry::class,
            'dsn' => (string)getenv('SENTRY_DSN'),
            'levels' => ['info'],
            'context' => true,
            'clientOptions' => [
                'traces_sample_rate' => (float)getenv('SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE')
            ]
        ],
```

Perfomance monitoring works fine, but the problem is that every event from `info` level logs as issue as well, so our `issues` page in sentry is full of successfull transactions now.

Is it posible to log `info` level only as part of perfomance monitoring and don't log these events as issues?